# Javascript - Correct username and password to enable another form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Alright, so I don't know if this is possible, or if there is an easier way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically I am using a Javascript form to enter in a username and password with a login button. If the username and password are entered correctly and you hit the login button, I would like the page to hide the "login form", and run another form. or if there is a way to disable the "patient info form" until the "login form" has been entered correctly.

I am completely lost on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I have so far.

```
<form name="recLogin">
  <table>

  <th>Receptionist Login</th>

  <tr><td>Username: 
  <input type="text"
  name="txtUsername"
  id="username"
  placeholder="Username"
  value="mayo" required ></td>

  <td>Password: 
  <input type="password"
  name="txtPassword"
  id="password"
  placeholder="Password"
  value="Please99!" required ></td>

  <td><input type="button"
  onClick="validateLogin();"
  value="Login"></td></tr>

  </table>
</form>


<form name="patientInfo">
  <table>

  <th>Patient Information</th>

  <tr><td>First Name:
  <input type="text"
  name="txtFName"
  id="firstName"
  placeholder="First Name";
  value=""></td></tr>

  <tr><td>Last Name:
  <input type="text"
  name="txtLName"
  id="lastName"
  placeholder="Last Name"
  value=""></td></tr>

  </table>
```

Javascript Code

```
function validateLogin()
{
var notValid = true;
var username = document.forms["recLogin"]["txtUsername"].value;
var password = document.forms["recLogin"]["txtPassword"].value;
username = username.toLowerCase();

if(username == "mayo" && password == "Please99!")
{
/*****COMPLETELY STUCK******/
alert("Entered Correctly");
notValid = false;
}
else
{ 
alert("I'm sorry but the username and password you entered are incorrect, please try again.");
}
}//End of validateLogin()
```

Comment: Give the tables IDs. After validating the login, set the login table's `style.display = 'none'` and the info table's `style.display = 'block'`.

Comment: On side note, try to avoid HTML tables for page layout. If I'm going to be a pedant, I should also mention that you should be using `fieldset`, `legend` and `label` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just as barmar mentioned,

Apply table ids like

```
<table id='receiptionist_table' style='display:block'>
  <th>Receptionist Login</th>
```

the block means this table will be shown when you first come on the page.
and

```
<table id='Patient_table' style='display:none'>
  <th>Patient Information</th>
```

we are using display none so that this form is hidden, you will now change styles inside your script as soon as login is successful which is:

```
if(username == "mayo" && password == "Please99!")
{
  document.getElementById('receiptionist_table').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('Patient_table').style.display='block';
  alert("Entered Correctly");
  notValid = false;
}
```

In the script you need to just play with styles. That's it!

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Adding IDs to the forms and adding and removing styles to those would be just as effective.